# Why java is not executing the overriden hashcode() method from user defined class?

Tags: java, object, hashcode

Even if you override, while calculating hash of the object before putting it  into hashmap as Key, it is still referring to hashcode method in Object class and giving some int value.

I have  overriden  one method which will just returning the same value for all the objects to test hashcode but every time it is getting the value form Object class's hashcode method which is implemented in native language.

If it is not executing the overriden hashcode method from user defined class then what is the purpose of implementing hash code?

```
public class Product { 
    public String name ; 
    public int id;
    public int hashcode(){ int result = 1; return result; } 
}
```

ideally hashcode of all product objects is 1 but i am getting something like 952115109
540724846...
why is this??

Comment: The `hasCode` method is not used (at least not solely used) to calculate the buckets in a HashMap.

Comment: Did you add `hashCode()` or `hashcode()` to your subclass?

Comment: @Narahari Babu Kannemadu Stop making noises, and put some code here.

Comment: public class Product {
 
 public String name ;
 

 public int id;
 public int hashcode(){
  int result = 1;
  return result;
 }
} 
this is my class. which is returning 1 always for all objects of type Product. ideally when you calculate hashcode it should be 1 but i am getting 952115109 why is this?

Comment: @hotzst You sure about that? Looking at the source it appears that the bucket is hashcode + numbre of buckets.

Comment: See http://javarevisited.blogspot.ch/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html "HashMap implementation calls hashCode method on Key object and applies returned hashcode into its own hashing function to find a bucket location"

Comment: While you are correct, it does some math on the hashcode, I think the previous post is very misleading and it sounds as if the `HashMap` selection of the bucket is not based on the hashcode.

Comment: What it does not do is run its own hashing function (except on strings for some reason).

Answer (score 6):

```
public int hashcode(){ ... }
```

must be

```
public int hashCode(){ ... }
```

Note that identifiers are **case sensitive** in Java.

To avoid such mistakes, use the `@Override` annotation:

```
@Override
public int hashcode(){
    ...
}
```

would produce a compile time error as there is no `hashcode()` method in the super class.

Answer (score 2):

`hashCode` not `hashcode`, in Java methods are case sensitive.

I recommend you use the [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) as then your IDE will tell you when you have a typo like that.

Comment: Got it thank you.. :)

Comment: Mark on the answers as correct then.

Answer (score 1):

You have written all letters of `hashcode()` in lower case but it should be  `hashCode()`

variables and methods in java are case sensitive.

```
public int hashCode()
```

is the method declared in Object class.

You are not really overriding `hashCode()` of Object class. You have added new method `hashcode()` instead of overriding.